# Lambda function to add headers to CSV file in s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have a data pipeline set up that exports the contents of a DynamoDB table to s3. However, it does not add headers to the CSV file. Apparently it's possible to use a Lambda function to append the headers to the CSV file but I am unsure how to go about this.

So far, using the AWS example, we can get the object, and upload it but it's the bit in the middle that we're struggling on.

```
function download(next) {
            // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            <<what goes here?!>
                        }
                    });
            });
        },
        function upload(contentType, data, next) {
            // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
            s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: dstBucket,
                    Key: dstKey,
                    Body: data,
                    ContentType: contentType
                },
                next);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<<what goes here?!>>` is where you modify your csv file. A basic example is something like this:

```
function transform(response, next) {
  //transform the buffer into a utf-8 string
  var csvAsString = response.Body.toString('utf-8'); 
  var withHeaders = '"Amount","FirstName","LastName","Email"\n' + csvAsString;

  //pass contentType/data to upload function in the waterfall
  next(null, 'text/csv', withHeaders);
},
```

This may be enough to get you by or if you need to do more complex transformations on the data you could look at using a csv library such as https://github.com/klaemo/csv-stream or https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv